# What hook do I have to do to know when image is loaded and painted? EasyHook/DLL Injection

Tags: c#, dll-injection, easyhook, apimonitor

I'm using easyHook to do a DLL injection to know when a text is written in a 3d party application window.

This application also draws an image in its windows. I know the path/name of this picture (let's say path is: C:\ImageLoadedByExternalProgramAndDrawnInTheWindow.png)

However, I don't know what to hook exactly in order to know when this image is called in order to be painted. What function shall I hook?

I took a look at API Monitor and saw this:

[image]

But I don't know how to use it properly so not sure what function is calling this. Or... I just have to hook RtlIsDosPath... in kernelbase.dll?

Samy

Comment: Are you looking for image loading? If so, you probably need to look for one of the file i/o functions.

Comment: And which one would that be? http://i.imgur.com/SrC4im9.png

Comment: You might need to track down where the image is used after it is loaded (you can set breakpoints in the debugger upon access to a particular section of memory - although now that I think about it that might only be for data writes). There is no guarantee that any API is used to process the image afterwards - could be GDI+, could be Direct3D, depends on the application.